# Get the content of a table based on html tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following table :

```
<table id="sample">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="toprow">
            <td style="width:25%"></td>
            <td style="width:25%">Number of Jurisdictions</td>
            <td style="width:25%">Per cent of total</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="leftcol">Europe</td>
            <td class="data">44</td>
            <td class="data">29%</td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I am using `beautifulsoup` to get the content of the table :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re
# Site URL
url = "http://archive.ifrs.org/Use-around-the-world/Pages/Analysis-of-the-IFRS-jurisdictional-profiles.aspx"
# Make a GET request to fetch the raw HTML content
html_content = requests.get(url).text
# Parse HTML code for the entire site
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
# print(soup.prettify()) # print the parsed data of html
# On site there are 2 tables with id="sample"
# The following line will generate a list of HTML content for each table
gdp = soup.find_all("table", id="sample")
print("Number of tables on site: ", len(gdp))
# Lets go ahead and scrape first table with HTML code gdp[0]
table1 = gdp[0]
# the head will form our column names
body = table1.find_all("tr")
# Head values (Column names) are the first items of the body list
head = body[0]  # 0th item is the header row
body_rows = body[1:]  # All other items becomes the rest of the rows
# Lets now iterate through the head HTML code and make list of clean headings

# Declare empty list to keep Columns names
headings = []
for item in head.find_all("td"):  # loop through all th elements
    # convert the th elements to text and strip "\n"
    item = (item.text).rstrip("\n")
    # append the clean column name to headings
    headings.append(item)
print(headings)
```

I was able to get the header :

```
['', 'Number of Jurisdictions', 'Per cent of total']
```

Now I want to get the content of the cells but I don't know how to loop through the `<td>` tag since its class may change to "leftcol" or "data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I would simplify this a bit:

```
gdp = soup.select("table#sample")[0]
rows = []
cols = []
for g in gdp.select('tr.toprow'):
    for c in g.select('td'):
        cols.append(c.text)
    
for g in gdp.select('tr:not(.toprow)'):
    row = []
    for item in g.select('td'):
        row.append(item.text)
    rows.append(row)
pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
```

Or you could simplify it even more (at the cost of making it, I believe, less readable) by using list comprehensions:

```
cols = [c.text for g in gdp.select('tr.toprow') for c in g.select('td')]
rows = [[item.text for item in g.select('td')] for g in gdp.select('tr:not(.toprow)')]
pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
```

Output:

```
                        Number of Jurisdictions     Per cent of total
0   Europe              44                          29%
1   Africa              23                          15%
2   Middle East         13                           9%
3   Asia and Oceania    33                          22%
4   Americas            37                          25%
5   Totals             150                          100%
```